Google Sheets / Apps Script - code lag sometimes means I am writing to wrong row
Maybe some of you have run into this same problem.
There is of course sometimes a lag between apps script and the actual sheet, particularly when getting/writing data to/from the sheet, like with range.getValues().
So here is the basic chain of events:

I get all of the data from a large 2D range.
I cycle through it row by row checking if the user has updated any of the data since this code last checked
If it HAS been changed, I do some stuff with the data
Then I overwrite the original row of data with the new data

This all works fine, but the problem is, since there can be a number of seconds between 1 and 4, if in the meantime the user has changed the order of the data (lets say they sort the sheet), then by the time the code is actually writing the data back to the row, the row has moved and it is overwriting the wrong data.
I added some code that, once it establishes the row to write back to and gets that range, it is actually grabbing the data in that range to check it again to make sure it is still the same, but all I am doing there is narrowing the lag gap to a second maybe. On rare occasions there are still instances where the user is changing the sheet within that narrow time gap. My fix made it less frequent, but it still can and does happen.
What can I do to avoid this problem?
Thanks!

BTW, script locking is not an option here since these are not two competing Apps Script functions, it is Apps Script vs a user simply using the spreadsheet. I also don't have the option to restrict users from sorting the data, or simply dragging rows around manually.

Please share your script and provide a minimal reproducible example.

Write all of the data back - both modified and unmodified.

How is the script triggered? Related question: How to lock spreadsheet while standalone script is running
